# What does read -r -a BUILD_ARGS_ARRAY <<< "$@" mean in bash?

Tags: bash, shell

I read some piece of code in [build.include](https://github.com/eclipse/che/blob/master/dockerfiles/build.include)

```
set -u
prepare_build_args() {
    IFS=',' read -r -a BUILD_ARGS_ARRAY <<< "$@"
    for i in ${BUILD_ARGS_ARRAY[@]}; do
    BUILD_ARGS+="--build-arg $i "
    done
}
```

I have difficulty in understanding this code because I am new to shell.

- Is `IFS` a variable assigned with value ','? Why it is followed by a `read` command?
- What does `-r -a` mean? and what does `<<<` do?
- BUILD_ARGS_ARRAY[@] is not defined before . and there is `set -u` which means unassigned variable will be recognized as error.Is it the problem of scope? And What does `[@]` mean?
- Finally,in my understanding BUILD_ARGS stored all the things in BUILD_ARG_ARRAY, but it is not returned out of the `prepare_build_args`function?

Comment: To be very clear, that's *extremely* buggy code, and you shouldn't be copying from it (or using it at all, for that matter).

Comment: (Also, "please explain this code" questions are generally considered too broad to be on-topic here unless they isolate only a single specific question, and show research already performed to attempt to answer it; see [How to handle “Explain how this ${code dump} works” questions](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/253894/how-to-handle-explain-how-this-code-dump-works-questions) on [meta]).

Comment: ...speaking to how `return` works in bash -- the only thing you can return is a single-byte integer used to determine exit status. Any other data needs to be either passed out on stdout, or set by modifying global variables as a side effect.

Comment: ...also, note that `var=value something` sets `var` to `value` in the environment *only during the execution of `something`*. And only during the *execution itself*, not during the expansions that form its argument list.

Comment: ...so, what the person who wrote this code *should* have done is `prepare_build_args() { build_args=( ); local arg; for arg; do build_args+=( --build-arg "$arg" ); done; }` -- after which `build_args` is an array, which should be expanded/used as `"${build_args[@]}"`; see BashFAQ #50 for details on how to do that correctly/safely.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking through the [Bash manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/) might be helpful.

- IFS is the [Internal Field Separator](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Word-Splitting.html#Word-Splitting), setting it before the read command applies it only for that command.
- The [read builtin command](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Bash-Builtins.html#Bash-Builtins) option `-r` stops backslashes mangling the data, and `-a` reads into an array (`BUILD_ARGS_ARRAY` in this case).
  `<<<` is a [here string](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Redirections.html#Here-Strings) which directs the [arguments of the function](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Special-Parameters.html#Special-Parameters) `prepare_build_args` to the `read` command.
- `BUILD_ARGS_ARRAY` is set by the `read` command. The `[@]` Bash syntax expands the [array](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Arrays.html#Arrays).
- [Variable scope](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Functions.html#Shell-Functions) is global unless the local builtin is used.

Comment: This describes the pieces, but it doesn't describe why combining them this way is buggy/hazardous -- which is probably important for any reader to know.

Comment: (f/e, the difference between `${foo[@]}` and `"${foo[@]}"` is critical; unquoted, `${foo[@]}` is identical to `${foo[*]}`).

Answer (score 0):

In short, this code:

- Concatenates all your function's arguments together into a single string (normally this is what `"$*"` does, but `"$@"` does it as well when used in a context where its result is evaluated as a single string).
- Splits that string on commas, storing the result in an array named `BUILD_ARGS_ARRAY`
- Takes the array, concatenates its arguments into a single string (again!), splits that string on whitespace, expands each component generated by that split operation as a glob operation, and iterates over the glob results.
- For each glob results, appends the string `--build-arg <result>` to `BUILD_ARGS`.

**This is extremely buggy, and should never be used by anyone.** To go into why in more detail:

- `"$@"` is intended for use where its result can be treated as a list. Expanding it in a string context throws away the original division between arguments, replacing them with the first character in `IFS` (in the context in which the expansion is done, *not* the expansion of the `read` in which the result is consumed).
- The unquoted `${foo[@]}` expansions make the behavior of this code sensitive to whether your arguments contain globbing characters, and if so, which files exist in the directory it's run in and whether the `nullglob`, `failglob`, or similar options are set. See the [shellcheck](https://shellcheck.net/) warning [SC2068](https://github.com/koalaman/shellcheck/wiki/SC2068).
- The net effect of this operation is to build a string which is presumably going to be expanded in generating a command line. Strings cannot be safely used in this way in the general case; see [BashFAQ #50](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/050) describing the pitfalls, caveats, and alternative approaches.

Comment: Note that this answer is flagged Community Wiki as I don't believe this question is narrowly-scoped enough to be on-topic here, so I'm not intending to collect reputation by answering it.